# Drawing Topological Diagrams and Importing Them to LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, mathcha

I am taking a course on point set topology so since I take my lecture notes using LaTeX I want a software or application from which I can sets and topological diagrams and import them to LaTeX.
[image]

For example, how could I create a set like this one using some software online.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you edit your question. The main sentence makes no sense as it is.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you drawing by hand on paper, scanning the drawings into a computer, and then you want to include them into a LaTeX file? What file format are the drawings in?

Comment: Hello, previously in my calculus courses I used to draw by hand and import them to latex, but recently I was trying to search for a software that draws diagrams. Basically like the topological figures and diagrams we see in research papers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) editor tool that export in `TikZ` code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,473); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 473

%Shape: Polygon Curved [id:ds062061472047211685] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}] (84.88,131.11) .. controls (105.27,98.89) and (176.5,59) .. (259.5,109) .. controls (342.5,159) and (349.88,214.11) .. (310.88,254.11) .. controls (271.88,294.11) and (205.5,283.33) .. (141.5,278.33) .. controls (77.5,273.33) and (127.5,267.33) .. (85.5,234.33) .. controls (43.5,201.33) and (64.5,163.33) .. (84.88,131.11) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp7561525131166351] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 1.69pt off 2.76pt}][line width=1.5]  (138.67,205.67) .. controls (138.67,175.48) and (163.14,151) .. (193.33,151) .. controls (223.52,151) and (248,175.48) .. (248,205.67) .. controls (248,235.86) and (223.52,260.33) .. (193.33,260.33) .. controls (163.14,260.33) and (138.67,235.86) .. (138.67,205.67) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9954039611629122] 
\draw    (234.5,170.33) -- (193.33,205.67) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp26480619419509255] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (191.83,204.17) .. controls (191.83,202.23) and (193.4,200.67) .. (195.33,200.67) .. controls (197.27,200.67) and (198.83,202.23) .. (198.83,204.17) .. controls (198.83,206.1) and (197.27,207.67) .. (195.33,207.67) .. controls (193.4,207.67) and (191.83,206.1) .. (191.83,204.17) -- cycle ;
% Text Node
\draw (113,107.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\LARGE]  {$U$};
% Text Node
\draw (300,264.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\LARGE]  {$X$};
% Text Node
\draw (174,200.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$x$};
% Text Node
\draw (199,175) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$\varepsilon $};
% Text Node
\draw (173,236.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$B_{\varepsilon }(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Point set topology.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: User without a minimal working example.

Comment: +1 for `Matcha`. :-)

Comment: @TrongVuong1998 LOL :-) ahahah. Sincerely I am discovering many options that I not knew before. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You might try using Windows built-in Paint (or MSPaint) program.  It wouldn't take much longer than drawing by hand, and the results can be in any of several convenient formats.  But I'm not clear on what more you hope the program will do.